# SPICE problem: Converter V/I scheme not working properly

Tags: wiring, proteus

[image]

I'm having a small urgent problem with a project: I don't understand why, when I connect the bottom left amplifier from the 4th pin to R2 (180 Ω), Proteus crashes.

What am I doing wrong and what would be a good fix for this?

Comment: U2A, pin-4 is supposed to be a power supply pin. What are you trying to achieve by connecting it to R2 & R4? Similarly with U1A, pin-8? And why are the rest of your opamps' supply pins unconnected?

Comment: Don’t know the answer but I have a suggestion. I’m wondering if it’s because pin 4 is already connected at component U2-A. Perhaps try disconnecting pin 4 at U2-A and connecting to pin 4 of U2-B instead.

Comment: When you say Proteus crashes, do you mean the program would not respond and close?

Comment: Alright so, I forgot to mention, I`m not sure if should power every amp individually; So I might be making a mistake there, I'm just needed to make everything work, and I can get the reading on the other side.